# Can't retrieve URL under test in Angular service, when testing with Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, angular-router

My application has processes relying on the current URL. I access it via `router.url` or `location.path()`, and it works well.

But **when Cypress runs**, the calls within the application `router.url` or `location.path()` **systematically returns '/'**, failing the subsequents actions based on the *current URL*.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private location: Location,
  ) { }

  doSomethingRelatedToUrl(): void {
    this.router.url; // returns systematically '/' when Cypress runs the tests !
    this.location.path(); // returns systematically '/' when Cypress runs the tests !
  }
}
```

Why is that? How can I get Cypress to sync the Angular router/location when I ask it to *visit* a URL under test?